# How to pass data from detail view to master view in iOS

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, segue

I'm studying the example *Your Second iOS App*: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011318-CH1-SW1

It uses segue to transit from the master view to detail view. How can I pass data from detail view to master view? I understand I should use delegate which is recommended, but when does the detail view call the delegate method?